# React State Object to Number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui-react

I am not able to have my `_.times` calculate correctly due to the object that is being returned. `console.log({template});` returns an object with `{Template: 5}` but when that is passed into my `_.times` it return an array(0). If I manually type 5 into the below section it will return the with `array(5)` with the gird columns displaying on the screen.

How can I use the value from the template to populate the times amount correctly which needs to be a number. I have attempted to `math.floor()` the value and `number()` the value which doesn't seem to work.

The section in Question.

```
  console.log({ template });

  const columns = _.times(5, (i) => (
    <Grid.Column key={i}>
      <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" />
    </Grid.Column>
  ));
```

Code

```
import _ from "lodash";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import HeaderBar from "./modules/header";
import "./BandsPageScreen.css";
// import Temp from "../../img/tempphoto.png";
// import Logo from "../../img/logo.png";
import { Dropdown, Grid, GridColumn, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";

const CustomizePhotoScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const [template, setTemplate] = useState(0);

  const options = [
    { key: 1, text: "2 Portrait Photos", value: 2 },
    { key: 2, text: "5 Photos", value: 5 },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {}, [template]);

  const handleSelection = (event, data) => {
    setTemplate(data.value);
  };
  console.log({ template });

  const columns = _.times(5, (i) => (
    <Grid.Column key={i}>
      <Image src="https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png" />
    </Grid.Column>
  ));

  const GenerateDropDown = () => {
    return (
      <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select Template"
        selection
        options={options}
        value={template}
        onChange={handleSelection}
      ></Dropdown>
    );
  };

  const GenerateGrid = () => {
    console.log({ columns });
    return <Grid>{columns}</Grid>;
  };
  return (
    <>
      <HeaderBar screen="photoinsert"></HeaderBar>
      <GenerateDropDown />
      <GenerateGrid />
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomizePhotoScreen;
```

Comment: Did you try this ? `_.times(template,`? What happens then? Is your {template} always logging the right value?

Comment: "returns an object with {Template: 5} but when that is passed into my _.times it return an array(0)."

Comment: That was it.. Thank you.. I thought that I had to use the {} but I guess that is only in the rendering section.

Comment: No, then your value becomes an object. You only want the number so `template` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to remove the {} from templates.